# I can't install emulator on my Android Studio installation, doesn't appear in sdkmanager list

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I can't install emulator for Android Studio on my linux installation.
It doesn't appears with "sdkmanager --list" command. I tried a lot of things, made researchs but nothing...

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...             
  Path                                 | Version | Description                 | Location                             
  -------                              | ------- | -------                     | -------                              
  build-tools;29.0.0                   | 29.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 29  | build-tools/29.0.0/                  
  patcher;v4                           | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4        | patcher/v4/                          
  platform-tools                       | 29.0.1  | Android SDK Platform-Tools  | platform-tools/                      
  platforms;android-28                 | 6       | Android SDK Platform 28     | platforms/android-28/                
  platforms;android-29                 | 1       | Android SDK Platform 29     | platforms/android-29/                
  sources;android-28                   | 1       | Sources for Android 28      | sources/android-28/                  
  system-images;android-28;default;x86 | 4       | Intel x86 Atom System Image | system-images/android-28/default/x86/
  tools                                | 26.1.1  | Android SDK Tools 26.1.1    | tools/
```

Available Packages:
  Path
[...] -> no emulator in it...

Comment: do you have space on your hdd?

Comment: Hi Erik, no problem of space on hdd.

Comment: Are you on an ARM64 host? I have the same problem on an ARM64 EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue on an ARM64 EC2 instance. The --list command does not show emulators, however i was able to setup an emulator on a x86_64 EC2 instance

Followed https://gist.github.com/atyachin/cf1690085173e1fabc07b9acc7af3de6

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31420163)